# What is the equivalent in php for this jquery code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, foreach

Jquery Code is this..

```
$.each(data, function(index, elem) {

    if (elem.stdid != stdid) {

        var cols = new Array(days);
        $.each(data, function(ind, el) {

            if (el.stdid == elem.stdid) {
                cols[el.day] = el.status.substring(0, 1);
                console.log(cols[el.day]);
            }
        });


        var row = "<tr><td class='txtcenter level4row'>"+ (counter++) +"</td><td class='txtcenter level4row'>"+ elem.student_name +"</td>";
        for ( i = 1; i<=cols.length; i++) {
            console.log(typeof(cols[i]));

            if (i%2 == 0) {
                row += "<td class='txtcenter' style='background: #e6f3fd;'>"+ ((typeof(cols[i]) == "undefined") ? '-' : cols[i]) +"</td>";
            } else {
                row += "<td class='txtcenter' style='background: #fff;'>"+ ((typeof(cols[i]) == "undefined") ? '-' : cols[i]) +"</td>";
            }
        }
        row += "</tr>";
        $(row).appendTo('#atnd-table tbody');

        stdid = elem.stdid;
    }
});
```

And my converted code is this:

```
<?php    foreach ($vrdetail as $row):?>
   <?php if ($row['stdid'] !== $stdid): ?>
                                                                                             <?php $cols =  array($days); ?>    
        <?php  foreach ($vrdetail as $rowTwo):?>
            <?php if ($rowTwo['stdid'] === $row['stdid']): ?>
                <?php  $cols[$rowTwo['day']] = substr($rowTwo['status'],0,1); echo $cols[$rowTwo['day']];?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php $tr =  "<tr>".
                 "<td colspan='3' style=''>". $counter++."</td><td>" . $row['student_name'] ."</td>"; ?>
    <?php $length = count($cols);
            for ($i=1; $i <= $length; $i++) { 
                    if ($i%2 === 0 ) {
                        $tr +=  "<td>".  ((gettype($cols[$i]) == 'NULL') ? '-' : $cols[$i]) ."</td>";                                               
                    }else{
                        $tr += "<td >".((gettype($cols[$i]) == 'NULL') ? '-' 
                                                        : $cols[$i]) ."</td>";
                    }
                 }  
            $tr +=  "</tr>";
            $stdid = $row['stdid'];                  
            ?>
                                                                                                    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

This Php Code is giving me an error on these lines:

```
 $tr +=  "<td>".  ((gettype($cols[$i]) == 'NULL') ? '-' : $cols[$i])."</td>";   

 $tr += "<td >".((gettype($cols[$i]) == 'NULL') ? '-' : $cols[$i]) ."</td>";
```

which says

> A PHP Error was encounterd
>   Severity: Notice  Message: Undefined offset: 1 Filename:
>   reportPrints/monthlyAttendanceReport_pdf.php Line Number: 151
>   Severity: Notice Message: Undefined offset: 2

and the same for the second line, but the offset is change only.

Comment: Use the dot '.' instead the plus '+' to combine. It is $tr .= not $tr +=

Comment: I have tried that but it is not working giving me same error...

Comment: @usama that is not the cause of the error, but in order for the code to do what you want, you need to fix that too.

Comment: @TimSeguine i have did that but i am getting the results but the error i am getting is same and row in a table is not appending every time when the for loop runs.any idea what should i do...?

Comment: Can you maybe `var_dump($days);` and post the results. There is something wrong with your `$cols` variable compared to how you are using it. You are trying to access an index that isn't there, but without seeing the data, that is a bit hard to diagnose. By reading the code, the way you are using it doesn't make sense, but that is all I can really say from here.

Comment: On a side note, why are you wrapping every single line in php open and close tags? There is no reason for that and it just makes everything almost impossible to read.

Comment: @TimSeguine Sorry for the late reply var_dump($days) is giving me string(2) "30" and var_dump($cols) is giving me array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "30" }

Comment: @TimSeguine I am beginer to PHP thnx for the suggestion next time i will keep that in mind... :)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 $tr .= "<td >".((gettype($cols[$i]) == 'NULL') ? '-' : $cols[$i]) ."</td>";
```

instead of

```
 $tr += "<td >".((gettype($cols[$i]) == 'NULL') ? '-' : $cols[$i]) ."</td>";
```

Comment: Thnx but it is still giving me error on these two lines i want to add a new row for how many time for loop is running ...

Answer (score 0):

On line 3 you have:

```
<?php $cols =  array($days); ?>
```

I am assuming `$days` is an array itself. The above statement will create an array `$cols` which would have only one element (i.e. an array) at index 0.

In the lines that result in error, you are trying to access the `$cols` array elements at index 1 and 2 which don't exist.

Comment: The $days variable is just a value which i am getting from input it has 30 in it...

Comment: If $days = 30, then $cols = array(30) will create an array with only 1 element, rather than array with 30 elements. If you want to create an array with 30 elements, use $cols = array_pad(array(), $days, '');